# [[ -n $VAR ]] vs [[ -n ${VAR:-} ]]

Tags: shell, ksh

What is the difference bettween

```
[[ -n $VAR ]]
```

and

```
[[ -n ${VAR:-} ]]
```

?

When should I use second test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `${VAR:-value}` substitutes `value` when `$VAR` is empty or unset. There is no particular reason (that I can think of) to use this syntax with an empty `value`.

Comment: This syntax is used in one script that I should modify. And I do not understand why is it used.